# Get audio data recorded in Real Time C++

Tags: c++, real-time, audio-recording

I found the code below that records and plays a wave recorded in 3 sec. I want to process audio data in real time, with the configuration Fs = 8000 Hz, and buffersize = 80 samples which means one frame duration = 0.01 sec, I want to get (read 80 samples and apply my work on it) something like this:

1. Start record
2. Every 0.01 sec getData and store it in a vector[80]
3. myresult = myFct(vector[80])
4. End record (if condition end Time).

So the problem is in number three, by reading some docs, it seems that I should use threads to getData. Any suggestion, please?

```
// RecPlayThreeSec.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")

short int waveIn[8000 * 3];

void PlayRecord();
void writedataTofile(LPSTR lpData, DWORD dwBufferLength);

void StartRecord()
{
    const int NUMPTS = 8000 * 3;   // 3 seconds
    int sampleRate = 8000;
    // 'short int' is a 16-bit type; I request 16-bit samples below
    // for 8-bit capture, you'd use 'unsigned char' or 'BYTE' 8-bit     types

    HWAVEIN      hWaveIn;
    MMRESULT result;

    WAVEFORMATEX pFormat;
    pFormat.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;     // simple, uncompressed format
    pFormat.nChannels = 1;                    //  1=mono, 2=stereo
    pFormat.nSamplesPerSec = sampleRate;      // 8.0 kHz, 11.025 kHz, 22.05 kHz, and 44.1 kHz
    pFormat.nAvgBytesPerSec = sampleRate * 2;   // =  nSamplesPerSec × nBlockAlign
    pFormat.nBlockAlign = 2;                  // = (nChannels × wBitsPerSample) / 8
    pFormat.wBitsPerSample = 16;              //  16 for high quality, 8 for telephone-grade
    pFormat.cbSize = 0;

    // Specify recording parameters

    result = waveInOpen(&hWaveIn, WAVE_MAPPER, &pFormat,
        0L, 0L, WAVE_FORMAT_DIRECT);

    WAVEHDR      WaveInHdr;
    // Set up and prepare header for input
    WaveInHdr.lpData = (LPSTR)waveIn;
    WaveInHdr.dwBufferLength = NUMPTS * 2;
    WaveInHdr.dwBytesRecorded = 0;
    WaveInHdr.dwUser = 0L;
    WaveInHdr.dwFlags = 0L;
    WaveInHdr.dwLoops = 0L;
    waveInPrepareHeader(hWaveIn, &WaveInHdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

    // Insert a wave input buffer
    result = waveInAddBuffer(hWaveIn, &WaveInHdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));


    // Commence sampling input
    result = waveInStart(hWaveIn);


    cout << "recording..." << endl;

    Sleep(3 * 1000);
    // Wait until finished recording

    waveInClose(hWaveIn);
    PlayRecord();
}

void PlayRecord()
{
    const int NUMPTS = 8000 * 3;   // 3 seconds
    int sampleRate = 8000;
    // 'short int' is a 16-bit type; I request 16-bit samples below
    // for 8-bit capture, you'd    use 'unsigned char' or 'BYTE' 8-bit types

    HWAVEIN  hWaveIn;

    WAVEFORMATEX pFormat;
    pFormat.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;     // simple, uncompressed format
    pFormat.nChannels = 1;                    //  1=mono, 2=stereo
    pFormat.nSamplesPerSec = sampleRate;      // 44100
    pFormat.nAvgBytesPerSec = sampleRate * 2;   // = nSamplesPerSec * n.Channels * wBitsPerSample/8
    pFormat.nBlockAlign = 2;                  // = n.Channels * wBitsPerSample/8
    pFormat.wBitsPerSample = 16;              //  16 for high quality, 8 for telephone-grade
    pFormat.cbSize = 0;

    // Specify recording parameters

    waveInOpen(&hWaveIn, WAVE_MAPPER, &pFormat, 0L, 0L, WAVE_FORMAT_DIRECT);

    WAVEHDR      WaveInHdr;
    // Set up and prepare header for input
    WaveInHdr.lpData = (LPSTR)waveIn;
    WaveInHdr.dwBufferLength = NUMPTS * 2;
    WaveInHdr.dwBytesRecorded = 0;
    WaveInHdr.dwUser = 0L;
    WaveInHdr.dwFlags = 0L;
    WaveInHdr.dwLoops = 0L;
    waveInPrepareHeader(hWaveIn, &WaveInHdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

    HWAVEOUT hWaveOut;
    cout << "playing..." << endl;
    waveOutOpen(&hWaveOut, WAVE_MAPPER, &pFormat, 0, 0, WAVE_FORMAT_DIRECT);
    waveOutWrite(hWaveOut, &WaveInHdr, sizeof(WaveInHdr)); // Playing the data
    Sleep(3 * 1000); //Sleep for as long as there was recorded


    waveInClose(hWaveIn);
    waveOutClose(hWaveOut);
}
int main()
{
    StartRecord();
    return 0;
}
```